# Excel Vba Worksheet data change

Tags: vba, excel

****EDIT***

I have updated my days as strings, now I am currently having a problem gettign the DayNum value back as an integer. My if then else statment is falling all the way through to saturday.

---

I'm not sure if this is possible. But I am trying to change which worksheet I am pulling data from based on which day it is. Where "day" is the variable.

the line of code I am havign trouble with and it repeats is

```
Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D24").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB34").Value
```

where Worksheets(Day) is the issue and i want it to change between sun - sat

I have worksheets titled sun-sat. the cells i need data from are the same from sheet to sheet but i need to pull the data to another sheet depending on the day for a meeting update printout.

```
       DayNum = Weekday(Today)
   If DayNum = 1 Then
        Day = "Sun"
    ElseIf DayNum = 2 Then
        Day = "Mon"
    ElseIf DayNum = 3 Then
        Day = "Tues"
    ElseIf DayNum = 4 Then
        Day = "Wed"
    ElseIf DayNum = 5 Then
        Day = "Thur"
    ElseIf DayNum = 6 Then
        Day = "Fri"
    Else: Day = "Sat"

    End If

    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D24").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB34").Value
    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D25").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB27").Value
    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D26").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB31").Value
    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D27").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB37").Value
    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D28").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB8").Value
    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D29").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB3").Value
    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D30").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB20").Value
```

Comment: Try `Now` instead of `Today`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using a string without quotes. When you set Day it should be the name of the sheet, therefore "Tues" not Tues.

**Also Weekday(Today) will not give you the correct output, try Weekday(Now) instead.**

```
Sub GatherData()

Dim Day As String
Dim DayNum As String
   DayNum = Weekday(Now)
   If DayNum = 1 Then
        Day = "Sun"
    ElseIf DayNum = 2 Then
        Day = "Mon"
    ElseIf DayNum = 3 Then
        Day = "Tues"
    ElseIf DayNum = 4 Then
        Day = "Wed"
    ElseIf DayNum = 5 Then
        Day = "Thur"
    ElseIf DayNum = 6 Then
        Day = "Fri"
    Else: Day = "Sat"

    End If

    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D24").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB34").Value
    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D25").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB27").Value
    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D26").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB31").Value
    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D27").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB37").Value
    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D28").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB8").Value
    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D29").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB3").Value
    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D30").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB20").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: this is really classic for `Select Case Weekday(Now)` , and then `Case 1` , `Case 2` etc.

Comment: No problem! The suggestion in @FatTony 's  answer to use a `Select Case Statement` is a good one, it makes your code a little easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding quotes around the date name in your `if` block.

Like so:

```
If DayNum = 1 Then
    Day = "Sun"
ElseIf DayNum = 2 Then
    Day = "Mon"
ElseIf DayNum = 3 Then
    Day = "Tues"
ElseIf DayNum = 4 Then
    Day = "Wed"
ElseIf DayNum = 5 Then
    Day = "Thur"
ElseIf DayNum = 6 Then
    Day = "Fri"
Else: Day = "Sat"

End If
```

Comment: that helped thank you. Now i just need to figure out why my if statement is falling through

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have forgot to initialize your days as a string.

```
Dim Day As String
Dim DayNum As String
   DayNum = Weekday(Today)
   If DayNum = 1 Then
        Day = "Sun"
    ElseIf DayNum = 2 Then
        Day = "Mon"
    ElseIf DayNum = 3 Then
        Day = "Tues"
    ElseIf DayNum = 4 Then
        Day = "Wed"
    ElseIf DayNum = 5 Then
        Day = "Thur"
    ElseIf DayNum = 6 Then
        Day = Fri
    Else: Day = "Sat"

    End If

    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D24").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB34").Value
    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D25").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB27").Value
    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D26").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB31").Value
    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D27").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB37").Value
    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D28").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB8").Value
    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D29").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB3").Value
    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D30").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB20").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really easy way to get the `Day` String:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim Day As String
    Day = LCase(Format(Date, "ddd"))
    Worksheets("Daily Info").Range("D24").Value = Worksheets(Day).Range("AB34").Value
End Sub
```

This assumes that the tabnames are all **lower case.**

Answer (score 0):

Like the other comments already explained, you need to wrap your `Strings` with **"**.

You're currently comparing a `String` with an `Integer` in your `if-statments` which causes your `if` structure to always go to the `else` statment.

Anyways, I´d also suggest you to use a `Select Case Statment` instead of repetative `If Then ElseIf Then`:

```
Dim Day As String
Select Case Weekday(Now)
    Case 1: Day = "Sun"
    Case 2: Day = "Mon"
    Case 3: Day = "Tues"
    Case 4: Day = "Wed"
    Case 5: Day = "Thur"
    Case 6: Day = "Fri"
    Case Else: Day = "Sat"
End Select

....
```

Since your `DayNum` is a `String` you have to compare it like this:

```
If DayNum = "1" Then
```

Or you just declare your `DayNum` as `Integer`, since the `return value` of `weekday()` is an `Integer` anyways